# curso de introduccion a la programacion en java ordenamiento

Tags: java

En la clase Muestra, cree el método darParesArreglo(), que retorna un arreglo de enteros con los números pares del arreglo original. Ayuda: Puede crear un ArrayList para almacenar los números pares del arreglo, y a partir del vector crear el arreglo que debe retornar y copiar los valores a este.

tengo el siguente codigo pero no me muestra los valores pares alguien me podria ayudar

```
/**
* Retorna un arreglo de enteros con los numeros pares presentes en el
* arreglo original
* @return Arreglo de enteros con los numeros pares del arreglo original
*/
public int[] darParesArreglo()
    {
        int num;
        int []arreglo = darCopiaValores();
        int [] arregloPares = new int[tamanio];
        
            for( int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++ )
            {
                
                if(arreglo[i]%2==0){
                    
                    arregloPares[tamanio]=arreglo[i];
                    
                   
                }
                
            }
            return arregloPares;
            
            
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La pregunta es confusa, el código que muestras no tiene ninguna instrucción para "mostrar" nada. Y además, no funcionará porque lanza una excepción. Da los detalles *exactos* de cómo se comporta el código y cuál es el problema observado; en el caso de que lance una excepción, indica qué excepción se lanza y donde. Puedes pulsar el botón de "Editar" para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Además, dale un título descriptivo a tu pregunta: cualquiera que lo lea pensaría que buscas que la comunidad haga tu tarea escolar (cosa que no hacemos aquí). Por favor, lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta parece bastante obvia, en ninguna parte de tu código existe la operación para mostrar los elementos de arreglo; al margen de eso hay algunos errores en tu código:

1. La variable `num` lo declaras pero no lo usas.
2. La variable `tamanio` no está declarado, a menos que está declarado como variable de clase y no lo muestras, si no es así te dará un error.

Yendo a la solución, en la descripción de tu pregunta dice en **Ayuda: Puede crear un ArrayList para almacenar los números pares del arreglo**, y eso vamos hacer porque al no saber la longitud del arreglo que tendrá los números pares lo mejor es usar arreglo dinámico.
Vamos a modificar el método `darParesArreglo`

```
public List darParesArreglo() {        
        int[] arreglo = darCopiaValores();
        List<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<>(); //creamos un ArrayList para los números pares

        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i] % 2 == 0) {
                pares.add(arreglo[i]);// el equivalente a arregloPares[tamanio]=arreglo[i];
            }
        }
        return pares;
    }
```

Ahora vamos crear un método para mostrar los elementos del arreglo de números pares

```
private void mostrarPares( List<Integer> listaPares){
        for(int i=0;i<listaPares.size();i++){
            System.out.println(listaPares.get(i));
        }
}
```

Otra forma de mostrar los elementos del arreglo

```
private void mostrarPares( List<Integer> listaPares){
        for(Integer i:listaPares){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Voy a ponerte un ejemplo completo basado en tu ejercicio.

Primero te muestro el método main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = darCopiaValores();
    List<Integer> listaPares = darParesArreglo(array);
    mostrarArrayPares(listaPares);
}
```

Básicamente aquí, ordenamos las acciones que queremos que haga nuestro programa.

**Primer paso:** Obtener un array inicial con una seria de valores.

```
public static int[] darCopiaValores() {

    int[] arrayPrincipal = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    System.out.print("Valores principales: ");
    for (int i : arrayPrincipal) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    return arrayPrincipal;
}
```

**Segundo paso:** Recorrer dichos valores del array inicial, averiguar que números son pares y guardarlos en una lista porque no sabremos el tamaño que tendrá. Hacer un *return* de la lista conseguida.

```
public static List<Integer> darParesArreglo(int[] array) {

    List<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            pares.add(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return pares;
}
```

Por ultimo, recorrer la lista y mostrar los numero pares obtenidos a partir del array inicial.

```
public static void mostrarArrayPares(List<Integer> listaPares) {
    System.out.print("\nLista de valores pares: ");
    for (Integer par : listaPares) {
        System.out.print(par + " ");
    }
}
```

**Código completo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = darCopiaValores();
        List<Integer> listaPares = darParesArreglo(array);
        mostrarArrayPares(listaPares);
    }

    public static int[] darCopiaValores() {

        int[] arrayPrincipal = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        System.out.print("Valores principales: ");
        for (int i : arrayPrincipal) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        return arrayPrincipal;
    }

    public static List<Integer> darParesArreglo(int[] array) {

        List<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                pares.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return pares;
    }

    public static void mostrarArrayPares(List<Integer> listaPares) {
        System.out.print("\nLista de valores pares: ");
        for (Integer par : listaPares) {
            System.out.print(par + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Valores principales: 1 2 3 4 5 
Lista de valores pares: 2 4
```

Espero que pueda servirte este ejemplo y si tienes algún problema, no dudes en preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar una Colección en vez de un Array así no te faltaran ni te sobraran espacios.

```
public Integer[] darParesArreglo() {
    int num;
    int[] arreglo = darCopiaValores();
    List<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo[i] % 2 == 0) {
            pares.add(arreglo[i]);
        }
    }
    return pares.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}

private int[] darCopiaValores() {
    return new int[]{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
}
```

Comment: Sin ser incorrecta, esta respuesta A) No le enseña al OP donde está el fallo en su código, así que la puede copiar pero seguir sin aprender nada y B) puede que no le sirva si el ejercicio le obliga a usar arrays.